# How to change Shopping Cart from updating one item to updating them all

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic, cart

It took a long time but I got a shopping cart working.  The thing is, in the nature of my business a customer could have hundreds of things in their cart, and the way I'm updating individual items is pretty primitive and can get tedious if there is a lot of items that needs updating.

For each row in the shopping cart database for a customer's cart, I generate the item's form and product information.  Each row therefore has it's own Update Item button.

```
$top_query = "SELECT t1.product_id, image_path, suggested_quantity, sales_info sku_item_number FROM product_customer_suggested_qty AS t1 
            LEFT JOIN product_images AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id 
RIGHT JOIN products AS t3 ON t1.product_id = t3.product_id          
            WHERE customer_id = '".$customer_id."'
            AND cart_visible != 0";
        //echo $top_query;
            $histresult = mysql_query($top_query) or die (mysql_error());

 <tr>
                <td width="181"><strong>Product</strong></td>
                <td width="181"><strong>Sales Info</strong></td>
                <td width="100"><strong>Suggested Qty</strong></td>
                <td width="100"><strong>Qty</strong></td>
                <td width="100"><strong>Image</strong></td>
                <td width="100"><strong>Add to Cart?</strong></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              $i =0;
              while($row=mysql_fetch_array($histresult))
            {
                echo '<tr height = "50px">';
                //We grab the product id as well as everything else we need.
                $customer_id= $row['customer_id'];
                $product_id= $row['product_id'];
                $link = $row['image_path'];
                $sku_item_number = $row['sku_item_number'];
                $suggested_quantity = $row['suggested_quantity'];

                 echo '
                 <form action="ezcopy.php? method="post"><td>'.$sku_item_number.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$suggested_quantity.'
    <input class="same" id="same'.$i.'" title="'.$i.'" name="same'.$i.'" type="checkbox" value ="'.$suggested_quantity.'"/> 
    <input name="customer_id" type="hidden" value="'.$customer_id.'">
    <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="'.$product_id.'">
    <input name="i" type="hidden" value="'.$i.'">
    </td>';

    echo '<td><input  class="qty" name="qty'.$i.'" id="qty'.$i.'" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4"></td>';
```

This is just a piece of the entire row, and it functions fully for both updating quantities, and allowing the user to automatically copy suggested values based on their history.

But if I want to make just one button on the bottom that says "Update All," and therefore make the entire shopping cart one large form, how do I modify the quantity form so that it can read in an unknown, dynamic number of items and update the database?  What's a good strategy for achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

After much struggling with Google, I finally found an example here.
http://www.theblog.ca/update-multiple-rows-mysql

The key is changing the form to one large one rather than many small ones, outside the row generating loop.

```
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($histresult))
            {
                echo '<tr height = "50px">';
                //We grab the product id as well as everything else we need.
                $customer_id= $row['customer_id'];
                $product_id= $row['product_id'];
                $link = $row['image_path'];
                $sku_item_number = $row['sku_item_number'];
                $suggested_quantity = $row['suggested_quantity'];
                $sales_info = $row['sales_info'];
                $item_id = $row['id_product_customer_suggested_qty'];

                 echo '<td>'.$sku_item_number;
                 //This array stores the item index.

                 echo '</td>';

                 echo '<td>'.$sales_info.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$suggested_quantity.'
    <input class="same" id="same'.$i.'" title="'.$i.'" name="same'.$i.'" type="checkbox" value ="'.$suggested_quantity.'"/> 
    <input name="item_id[]" type="hidden" value="'.$item_id.'">
    <input name="customer_id[]" type="hidden" value="'.$customer_id.'">
    <input name="product_id[]" type="hidden" value="'.$product_id.'">
    <input name="i" type="hidden" value="'.$i.'">
    </td>';

    echo '<td><input  class="qty" name="qty[]" id="qty'.$i.'" type="text"size="4" maxlength="4"></td>';
```

The first key is how the input names have changed.  They are now all arrays.  At the end of the row generating loop is a submit button.  Then, what happens upon submit is the next key.

```
foreach($_POST['item_id'] as $key=>$item_id)
{ 
    $qty = $_POST['qty'][$key];
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'][$key];
    $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'][$key];

    if (!empty($qty))
    {
        echo 'Product is '.$product_id.'<br>';
        echo 'Quantity requestesd is '.$qty.'<br><br>';
        //perform UPDATE query as that inidividual item
        }
}
```

This dynamically grabs every existing row in the form, each one made unique by the item_id.  We can now perform update queries, only as needed.  This is a really powerful trick.